# Удалить удалить из строки все цифры и определенные символы?

Tags: php

Хочу удалить из строки все цифры и определенные символы.

Делаю так:

```
preg_replace('/^[0-9.\-%]+/', '', $str);
```

Это от части работает, но к примеру не удаляет если в строке будет:

> 20% хлопок

то **20%** не удаляется.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: ты случаем не пытаешься кодированный url парсить ? :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет

Comment: `/[0-9.\-%]+/gm` https://regex101.com/r/Mzaqcv/1

Comment: @nazarpunk `Unknown modifier 'g'`

Comment: Можете удалить модификаторы.